# how to use inner join in my condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like these

```
   c_ID    name
    ---   ------
    7      a
    6      a
    5      a
    4      d
```

AND

```
   c_ID    photo
  -----   ------
    7       1
    6       1
    5       0
    4       1
```

How can i select records that name is `a` and photo is `1` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *  /*TODO: Add specific column(s) you want here*/
from   table1
       join table2
         on table1.c_ID = table2.c_ID
where  table1.name = 'a'
       and table2.photo = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 AS name LEFT JOIN table2 AS photo ON name.c_ID = photo.c_ID 
WHERE name.name = 'a' and photo.photo = 1
```

This being said, the way your example looks maybe you could normalize your two tables into one table with the fields c_ID, name and photo

Comment: Why `LEFT JOIN`? Your `WHERE` clause converts it back to an `INNER` one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT table1.c_id, table1.name, table2.photo
  FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
 ON table1.c_id = table2.c_id
   AND table1.name = 'a'
   AND table2.photo = 1
```

Comment: You have a hanging `INNER JOIN` with no `ON`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.c_ID = t1.c_ID
WHERE t1.name = 'a' AND t2.photo = 1
```

It is good practice not to use upper case characters in databases.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.c_ID, table1.name, table2.photo              // desired fields
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.c_ID=table2.c_ID   // joining tables on common keys
WHERE table1.name='a' AND table2.photo=1;                  // desired condition
```